# php mysql share data to msql

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql-server

I have a set of mysql data that i want to share to a friend using asp.net.

My question is what is the best way for me to share some tables. He can read only the datas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have him crawl a page that displays all the data from your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply give access to mysql db

Comment: well i can do that but he will see the other tables and settings! thats the point :D

Comment: you can specify permissions in mysql. like readonly for single table and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You may create View of the tables for which you want other application to allow.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another account that can access the database and give the account limited access rights. So he will only be able to read the data and not edit the data. But using asp you can create a website of sorts that displays the data to your friend in a easy to read format. But personally I am a php fan

Comment: Then use asp to create an XML document with the correct structure